# Formatting URLs and opening them

Tags: swift, string, url, cocoa, appkit

I received random URLs as part of API calls. So I don't know what I am getting.

I want to do two things with it.

1. Format it and display it in a label `NSTextField(labelWithString:)`
2. To allow the user to open it in a browser (Safari or their preferred browser) with `NSWorkspace.shared.open(_:)`

I've always force unwrap URL structs because I personally found that it never fails and I did some testing although not rigorously.

I want to format URLs into something like this.

1. `https://www.google.co.uk` -> `google.co.uk`
2. `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program` -> `en.wikipedia.org`
3. `https://blog.toyota.co.uk/toyota-production-system-glossary` -> `toyota.co.uk`

and so on, you get the general idea.

I used to do something like this.

```
let google = "https://www.google.co.uk"
let googleURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.uk")!
let formattedGoogleURL = googleURL.host!

print(formattedGoogleURL)
// prints www.google.co.uk
```

I came across this extension.

```
extension URL {
    var formatted: String {
        (host ?? "").replacingOccurrences(of: "www.", with: "")
    }
}
```

And the outcome produces.

```
// Let's try with the extension instance property
print(googleURL.formatted)
// prints google.co.uk
```

One day I received this URL as part of an API call.

`https://divinations.substack.com/p/linkedins-alternate-universe##`

And it crashed my app. I tried opening it in Safari and it opened fine. So why would the URL struct return nil for it? I assumed if it open in Safari then it should not return nil for the URL struct.

```
let linkedIn = "https://divinations.substack.com/p/linkedins-alternate-universe##"
let linkedInURL = URL(string: "https://divinations.substack.com/p/linkedins-alternate-universe##")

print(linkedInURL)
// prints nil
```

I found out that it is because of `##`.

```
let modifiedLinkedInString = "https://divinations.substack.com/p/linkedins-alternate-universe"
let modifiedLinkedInURL = URL(string: "https://divinations.substack.com/p/linkedins-alternate-universe")

print(modifiedLinkedInURL)
// prints Optional(https://divinations.substack.com/p/linkedins-alternate-universe)
// the culprit is ##
```

This incident taught me to basically never force unwrap URL structs because some URL will return nil.

I modified the extension into this.

```
extension URL {
    var formatted: String {
        (host ?? "").replacingOccurrences(of: "www.", with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.inverted)
    }
}
```

Therefore...

```
// Force unwrap the URL struct because the extension property will take care of illegal characters
print(modifiedLinkedInURL!.formatted)
// prints divinations.substack.com
```

So that seems fine and so I thought I was done for life.

One day as part of an API call, I ran into this URL, `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leary–Lettvin_debate`

```
let wikipedia = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leary–Lettvin_debate"
let wikipediaURL = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leary–Lettvin_debate")

print(wikipediaURL!.formatted)
// crashed my app

print(wikipediaURL)
// prints nil
```

My extension will not work. The Wikipedia URL works fine in Safari and I don't know what to do about this. How can I make sure that my app will never crash due to arcane URL rules?

There must be a way to format a url without having it to crash your app and the ability to open it with `NSWorkspace.shared.open(_:)`.

If it open in Safari then it should work in my app. I don't have control over the API data. I now have to deal with arcane URLs rules otherwise it generally works fine. I will never force unwrap due to two incidents and I expect even more with the way I am dealing with it.

Comment: Force unwrapping dynamic URLs is a recipe for failure. URLs cannot contain any characters, only a specific subset of characters, so when working with dynamic characters, you always need to sanitise those URLs and make sure they are correctly encoded to only contain valid characters.

Comment: I need to sanitise the entire URL. Not just parts of it. `. urlQueryAllowed` and `. urlPathAllowed` only does parts of it. Also how can I check that I don't percent-encode it twice?